# Power BI substruct from salary for each person and month

Tags: powerbi

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYN8B.png)

Hi ,

I have this table in power bi . Each person has lines for each month passes . 5 months equals to 5 appearances in the list. for each line and the number of days ( between START AND END column) i want to substract from the MONEY column the MONEY PER MONTH COLUMN and keep the differnce .After this differnce to be substracted again with the column MONEY PER MONTH from this row until i have 0 . The only catch is that i want if the difference( happens a lot of times at month 5 out of 5 ) if the MONEY PER MONTH column is less than 20 , i want it to be 20 and the before result 240. After the last month when a new name record comes the money again to be 1040

BASICALLY I WANT TO FORM THE RED LINED COLUMN IN IMAGE BELOW [COLUMN THAT I WANT TO ADD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW5mP.png)

Comment: instead of explaining that long of your data structure, you'd better give sample dataset and expected result according to the sample dataset...

Comment: i added an extra  image with the column